# Resize the text between screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, resolution, screen-size, text-size

I'm trying to support all differents screen sizes, but now i want to adjust the textsize.

But i change the size of the text with 2 different way:

- In the Layout XML:

  ```
          android:textSize="15dp"
  ```
- In the java files:

  ```
  TextView tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
  tv2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
  tv2.setTextSize(14);
  ```

So how can i support the textsize between the different screen size ?

Comment: Why not just use different folders for your xml for the various screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You could find out the size of the display and according to it to change the text size using something like this:

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

int textSize;
switch(screenSize) {
     case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
         textSize = 24;
         break;
     case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
         textSize = 18;
         break;
     case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
         textSize = 14;
         break;
     default:
         textSize = 15;
}
```

And then:

```
 TextView tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
 tv2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
 tv2.setTextSize(textSize);
```

The values I set are just for example

Comment: But i have to put your function in all class, i think i'm gonna create a specific class to do it. I'll try it

Comment: Okay, say then if you succeeded :)

Comment: Its possible to do something automatic ? with values or dimens xml files for exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text size in dp is a bad idea. always specify text sixes in sp.

in XML

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```

in Java

```
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
```

Comment: So it's gonna resize the text ?

Comment: specifying the textsize in sp will display right size in all screen sizes/densities. This is what android documentation says here in 2nd paragraph
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: Its talk about density too, but ill try it :) And i can do sp in xml too ?

Comment: yes sp can be used in xml too. use "sp" only for textsize and "dp" for everything else